# How can i add the current date to each of my pages in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i'm fairly new to ruby and I want to be able to display the current date on each of my pages in the format (Monday 1 January). Also, which files would i have to edit?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add an element to your layout file (/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb) with this code:

```
<%= Date.today.strftime("%A %-d %B") %>
```